# XMLConfiguration to String

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-config

I'm using the Apache Commons Configuration. How can I get directly a String of the XMLConfiguration without saving it to a file?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution, it is possible via the StringWriter:

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
config.save(stringWriter);
System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

[**org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.toString()**](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs_1.1/org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration%29)

> public static String
>   **toString**(Configuration configuration)
>
> ```
> Get a string representation of the key/value mappings of a configuration.
>
> Parameters:
>     configuration - the configuration 
> Returns:
>     a string representation of the configuration
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I think I don't quite get it. Is there also a way to get the XML representation (as a string) of the configuration? I need to print the correct XML syntax of the configuration.